# Upgrade to new XCode; can't built in Xamarin

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios

I think that one of the last XCode upgrades that came in last week appears to have broken my Xamarin iOS builds.  They fail with:

```
Failed to locate a valid instance of CoreSimulatorService in the bootstrap.  Adding it now.
```

Or

```
.../SignInUniversalController_iPhone.storyboard: Error: 2016-07-31 12:11:38.046 ibtoold[23284:2756861] [MT] IBPlatformTool: *** Failed to launch tool with description <IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x7fce44256b20> System content 1x for IBCocoaTouchFramework-NineOneAndLater w/ default fidelity: 
Failed to find or create execution context for description <IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x7fce44256b20> System content 1x for IBCocoaTouchFramework-NineOneAndLater w/ default fidelity (Failure reason: Software caused connection abort): Failed to find a suitable device for the type SimDeviceType : com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-1x with runtime SimRuntime : 9.3 (13E230) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-3 (Failure reason: Failed to create SimDeviceSet at path /Users/eric/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/IB Support/Simulator Devices. You'll want to check the logs in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator to see why creating the SimDeviceSet failed.): Failed to initialize simulator device set. (Failure reason: Failed to subscribe to notifications from CoreSimulatorService.): Error returned in reply to notification request: Connection invalid (Failure reason: Software caused connection abort)
2016-07-31 12:11:46.096 ibtoold[23284:2756861] [MT] IBPlatformTool: Wrote failed marshalling request diagnostics to path: /var/folders/t9/t9xl93t50ql14mr0lxmmw_2r0000gn/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2016-07-31_12-11-46_067000
Error: Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach "/var/folders/t9/t9xl93t50ql14mr0lxmmw_2r0000gn/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2016-07-31_12-11-46_067000".
```

The logs mentioned in the first error message doesn't appear to be more verbose than the above:

```
Failed to find or create execution context for description <IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x7fce44256b20> System content 1x for IBCocoaTouchFramework-NineOneAndLater w/ default fidelity (Failure reason: Software caused connection abort): Failed to find a suitable device for the type SimDeviceType : com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-1x with runtime SimRuntime : 9.3 (13E230) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-3 (Failure reason: Failed to create SimDeviceSet at path /Users/eric/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/IB Support/Simulator Devices. You'll want to check the logs in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator to see why creating the SimDeviceSet failed.): Failed to initialize simulator device set. (Failure reason: Failed to subscribe to notifications from CoreSimulatorService.): Error returned in reply to notification request: Connection invalid (Failure reason: Software caused connection abort)

Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to find or create execution context for description <IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x7fce44256b20> System content 1x for IBCocoaTouchFramework-NineOneAndLater w/ default fidelity, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fce44152c40 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fce441b8150 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to subscribe to notifications from CoreSimulatorService., NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize simulator device set., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fce44155b00 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo=0x7fce441c31b0 (not displayed)}}}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to create SimDeviceSet at path /Users/eric/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/IB Support/Simulator Devices. You'll want to check the logs in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator to see why creating the SimDeviceSet failed., NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to find a suitable device for the type SimDeviceType : com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-1x with runtime SimRuntime : 9.3 (13E230) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-3}}}
```

This is an iPhone project, but uses a Universal component; I note that since the above says iPad.

When it fails, it opens up the Storyboard editor and it appears to be OK there; there's nothing that seems surprising at first glance.

```
XCode: Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)
Xamarin: Latest Stable; no updates available
```

Any insight or thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you opened Xcode after updating it to make sure you can create a project with it? Sometimes it does some "first time" initializations that need to be done first.

Comment: Yes, I have... actually, it produces the same issue on compilation :/.  `/Users/eric/Desktop/Test/Test/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard: Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach all crash logs from ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports.`

Comment: Interesting. If Xcode doesn't work, the Xamarin tooling certainly won't work. I didn't see much on the web about that error. Try re-installing Xcode.

Comment: Understood -- although since I never use XCode directly, you can understand the assumption.  Anyhow, uninstalling and reinstalling XCode has not changed this for me.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Absolutely, I totally understand. I'm shooting in the dark here... Are you using the latest OSX version (10.11.X)? I think 7.3 requires it. Maybe try an older version of Xcode (7.3)

Comment: I'm now beyond this.  Exact steps are unclear, but it started working again after a reboot.  Not sure what that is about...